# Selenium xUnit not working consistently with IE

Tags: selenium, xunit.net

I'm creating tests using Visual Studio/Selenium/xUnit and I've just come across a command that doesn't work in IE. I have a screen with a list of items, each with a checkbox to it's left and I need to check that checkbox and then click on Save. I've tried CSSSelector and XPath and neither works. The command executes but neither the checkbox nor the Save button is clicked. If I run the same test in FireFox it works perfectly.

This is the first test I've written (of maybe 25) that doesn't work in IE. Anyone else have this problem? Know of a workaround (other than just test in FireFox)? We need to test in IE since that's what most of our customers have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this only doesn't work while debugging (stepping through the code). If I just run it it seems to work.